# C++ number.ToString("F") choose as decimal separator

Tags: c++, textbox, decimal-point, object-to-string

I am using a textBox to display a double value.

```
     double Zahl = 3.2343;
     textBox1->Text = Zahl.ToString("F");
```

The result is 3,23. How can I set the decimal separator that is used for displaying on my own?

I found this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx
So I tried the following:

```
    double Zahl = 3.2343 
    textBox1->Text = Zahl.ToString("F", en-US);
```

But I am just getting a compiler error.

Comment: Can you share the compiler error that you are getting..?

Comment: What language do you think you're using, and what are you actually using? C++ does not have a `.ToString()` method. In fact, `double` has no methods on it whatsoever.

Comment: @MSalters that seems like C# syntax... Talking about C# here and giving an answer to it as well makes me think apocalypse is nearer...

Answer (score 0):

According to the (C#) docs you linked to it looks like it needs to be:

```
textBox1->Text = Zahl.ToString("F", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));
```

Answer (score 0):

First, this isn't C++, since double havent method. It's probably C# or some kind of managed thing.

No matters, you have the answer on your link :

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-us");
```

then, use the ci object as the second parameter of ToString (see the example section on your link :) )

Comment: I started programming in C++ with Visual C++ some weeks ago. Now I want to get familiar with the Windows Forms Applications. So I just dragged a textBox and tryed to let it display a number. 
`private: System::Void textBox1_TextChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    double Zahl = 3.2343;
    textBox1->Text = Zahl.ToString("F");
    }`
I tried it with `CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-us");` but I had no success. Is it C# code? Does that mean that I should better learn C# if I want to generate Windows Form Applications? And how do I get a \newline when answering?:)

Comment: @JoachimRosenberger, to work over Windows Form Applications you can choose either... Your current code belongs to C# yes and won't work in C++... If you are more interested in just drag and drop I'd suggest you to work over C# as C++ will need more efforts comparatively else welcome to the community... Check [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/2605/), as it might help u understand...

New line in comments doesn't work yet... You can try endl... ;)